# Open Bootstrap Model with own function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have an asp.net web application.
When I click on my button a modal should be opened this is my button:

```
<input type="button" class="mybutton" data-toggle="modal"     data-target="#mymodal" value="Open Model" />
```

This works fine but I would prefer to to it like that:

```
<input type="button" class="mybutton" onclick="showModal()" value="Open Model" />
```

with:

```
function showModal() {
      $('#mymodal').toggle();
  }
```

but when I do it that way and click on the button the modal doesn´t show up and it is like the whole page freezes. But I don´t get any error warnings.
If anyone has an idea I would really appriciate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See Bootstrap docs for [modal methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-methods).

```js
function showModal() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="button" class="mybutton btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal()" value="Open Model" /> 

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal content
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You also have other methods to interact with modal, for example:

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle'); // Show if closed, close if shown
$('#myModal').modal('show'); // Show modal
$('#myModal').modal('hide'); // Hide modal
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use any of the below.

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

You can see more here: [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)